How to disable automatic opening of metamask widget when installing the widget for the first time?
How to disable automatic opening of metamask widget when installing the widget for the first time?
I use chromedriver to load the metamask folder
crx_meta = f'{os.getcwd()}/Extention/Metamask'
options.add_argument(f'--load-extension={crx_meta }')
I downloaded Metamask from https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/releases
